# How to escape double quotes in JSON?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a json string containing double quotes.

```
var json = @"{
                 ""key"": ""<a href='#'>I want to use a double quote instead of single quote for this href</a>""
             }";
```

Any tips?

EDIT: Included the extra double quote

EDIT 2: To be clear, I need `<a href='#'>` to become `<a href="#">`